# What is use of @ViewChild if we cannot change properties or manipulate them from Parent Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular-directive, viewchild

I got 2 components - home & about. In both I inject a third (child) compnonent - hearts. Now I am manipulation the value of 'age' property in hearts (set to default as '23') using @viewChild from 'home component'. I see that value seems changed in view of 'home Component' but not in 'about component'.

> **My Questions:**
>
> 1. How does the value seem to be changed in 1st component but not in second -- this means modal or value does not get changed in 'hearts
>    component' (that's why not updated in About component) -- but then how
>    does this seem to get changed to '33' in home component?
> 2. If the value of 'child component property' cannot be changed via parent using @viewChild -- then what the use of accessing from Parent.
>    Why then not directly just use the @input decorator -- it does better
>    job. Isn't it?

**1 - app.component.html**

```
<app-home></app-home>
<app-about></app-about>
```

**2a - home.component.html**

```
<app-heart #ref1></app-heart>
<button (click)="alpha()">click</button>
```

**2b - home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('ref1') ref1: HeartComponent;

alpha(){
  this.ref1.age = 33;
}
```

**3 - about.component.html**

```
<app-heart></app-heart>
```

**4 - heart.component.ts**

```
age = 23;
```

**Snapshot (on click of button)**

[image]

Comment: can you please share a sample(stackblitz link) on same

Comment: its pretty simple code, you can test on your device. I only shared relevant part. If I share full code, nobody will look at 'long snippet of spammed lines'.

Comment: yeah right i agree but i'm kinda away to build a sample so just looking for a rough sample to sort this out.

Comment: You have two different instances of `<app-heart></app-heart>`, so the value is not updated both places. They live their own lives (If I understood the question correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different instances of `<app-heart></app-heart>`, so they will keep their own states, which means a change in one of the instances does not affect the other.

The same goes if you use the `@Input()`-decorator, the value only updates on the instance you use it on.

When using an `@Input()`-decorator, you do not have to set the desired value explicit as you do using the `@ViewChild()`-decorator.

You are also decoupling the relation between components when you use `@Input()` instead of `@ViewChild()`